# Android - Cannot set gallery image to ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, image

I've looked through tons of posts and cannot figure out why I can't get this to work.  All I want to do is have the user click a button that opens up the gallery app.  Then the user selects a picture which automatically closes out the gallery and goes back to my application where it automatically sets that image to an ImageView.

So far, I have it working all the way up until it goes back to my application.  It seems to all be fine but the image never shows up in the ImageView.

Here is the XML code for the ImageView:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

At the beginning of my activity I set the ImageView with this:

```
 ImageView targetImage;
```

And here is the rest of my code to get the image and set it to my ImageView.  There is a button that launches "setGunImage".

```
public void setGunImage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            targetImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tested it on both the simulator with the sd card enabled and an image loaded into and also on a real device.  Both give the same behavior.  It goes through the gallery steps fine but when it goes back to my application there is no image loaded in the ImageView.

I tried changing the data to a bitmap and setting that but it never showed up either.  I know it's probably something super simple that I'm just not seeing so hopefully a fresh pair of eyes can point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Imran solution should work fine .............. and you can also try this way

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            InputStream stream = null;
         if( resultCode==RESULT_OK)
           {
              if(requestCode==SELECT_PICTURE)
               {
                try {
                    // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        bitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                                targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (stream != null)
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

}
```

from [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: ohh in this case requestCode == REQUEST_CODE should be requestCode==SELECT_PICTURE...

Comment: After I posted that question, I realized what you just said and changed the code to SELECT_PICTURE.  Unfortunately, I still get the same problem.  It loads the gallery just fine but when I select a picture, it send me back to my app and the ImageView stays blank.  I cannot figure out why it won't set the image.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I pasted in your updated code and the problem is still there.  It just won't display the picture in the ImageView.  Thanks for trying to help me figure this out!

Comment: Could there be a problem in the XML file prohibiting the image from showing up?  If I preload an image in the ImageView, it works fine.  The ImageView is in a LinearLayout which is inside of a ScrollView.

Comment: can you put a taost after "targetImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);" with show() and check ?

Comment: Ok I added the toast and the toast displays correctly so it is definitely getting that far.

Comment: Update: I copied the code you gave me exactly into a new test project and it works perfectly but still doesn't work in my application.  I'm really starting to wonder if something in the XML is messing it up.  Don't know what that would be but I'll keep looking.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  I had a stupid line of code hiding in my onResume() that was resetting that ImageView.  I just now caught it.  Sorry for all the hassle and thank you very much for your help.  I marked your answer as complete.

Answer (score 1):

you are passing URI in setImageURI so fist get path of image using `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA` and URI then pass path of image in setImageURI.
try this way:

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(requestCode==SELECT_PICTURE)
        {
            targetImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath=getPath(selectedImageUri);
            targetImage.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri)
        {    
        String[] projection={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
        Cursor cursor=managedQuery(uri,projection,null,null,null);
        int column_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        return cursor.getString(column_index); 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply but unfortunately it still doesn't work.  It loads the gallery and lets me choose a picture just fine.  After choosing the photo it kicks back to my app and the ImageView is still blank.  Any other ideas?